# Unable to reproduce the Pro Git construction of a commit

Tags: git

I'm building my own implementation of Git, and have reached a point where my output (and that of `git` itself) has diverged from Pro Git's.

Specifically, right now I'm following through the construction at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects to build a commit. But I can't seem to get the same commit hash out, even after fixing the entire contents of the commit data. I've written a little program to write out and read in commits, and that program is able to round-trip the commit data I've specified, but it gets the "wrong" commit hash. That "wrong" commit hash is consistent with my local `git`, but not with Pro Git's printed output.

Reproducing this in zsh for convenience (I get exactly the same commit hash as `git` here does, when I use my own implementation of Git):

```
➜  git --version
git version 2.26.1 
➜  rm -rf .git
➜  export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2009-05-22T18:09:34+00:00-0700"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="schacon@gmail.com"
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Scott Chacon" \
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2009-05-22T18:09:34+00:00-0700" \
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="schacon@gmail.com" \
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Scott Chacon" \

git init

# First commit.
echo 'version 1' > test.txt
git add test.txt
echo 'First commit' | git commit -F -
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/Patrick/Documents/Experiments/foo2/.git/
[master (root-commit) 70d4408] First commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.txt

➜  git cat-file -p 70d440
tree d8329fc1cc938780ffdd9f94e0d364e0ea74f579
author Scott Chacon <schacon@gmail.com> 1243040974 -0700
committer Scott Chacon <schacon@gmail.com> 1243040974 -0700

First commit
➜
```

By contrast, Scott's output from the book is:

```
$ echo 'First commit' | git commit-tree d8329f
fdf4fc3344e67ab068f836878b6c4951e3b15f3d

$ git cat-file -p fdf4fc3
tree d8329fc1cc938780ffdd9f94e0d364e0ea74f579
author Scott Chacon <schacon@gmail.com> 1243040974 -0700
committer Scott Chacon <schacon@gmail.com> 1243040974 -0700

First commit
```

Note that I've got the same data as far as is observable from the book's output, but a different commit hash (mine is 70d44, Scott's is fdf4f).

Why have we got different hashes? Is this something to do with the level of zlib compression changing, perhaps? That seems like the only possible variable here, but my results stay the same regardless of the level of zlib compression I use (insofar as the ability to vary this is exposed to .NET's `Ionic.Zlib`). One possible explanation is that `zlib` has changed since the book was written, and the more recent `zlib` is used both by `Ionic.Zlib` and `git` itself at version 2.26.1; but it hasn't *totally* changed, because I get the right hashes for the tree and blob objects I've tried so far.

I've been very careful about line endings: my commit message has a newline on the end, as does Scott's, because both come from `echo`. Anyway, I'm confident in my result: I can round-trip commits using my homemade Git implementation, and my homemade Git implementation agrees with my `git` (and not with Scott) on this.

Comment: You're getting the right hashes.  I think the reason you're not getting the hash ID he got is that *for that example of that section of the Pro Git book* he did not have those six environment variables exported.  So the date-and-time-stamp weren't those he showed. This is the kind of glitch that happens when you try to write a book :-)

Comment: Note, by the way, that the hash IDs are computed on the data *before* compression, so that's just a red herring here.

Comment: @torek But the date and time-stamp are shown in the `git cat-file` output that he gives, and all his samples are internally consistent; that's how I obtained them. (He later gives a complete `git log`, which is also consistent with me.) You are quite right that the data has to be different for the hashes to be different, though; I don't know why I didn't think of that. So you've very helpfully sliced away the wrong thing I was looking at, but I'm still confused.

Comment: Ah, I see you found a somewhat different variant of same problem. In general what happens here is that you write some page(s) of a book and quote some actual repository hashes. Then you go to revise the page(s) and re-do some of the operations and get different hashes, and since you've already remarked that hashes depend on every byte, including date-and-time stamps, you don't notice that you've built something that, by itself, looks inconsistent later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @torek, I thought of looking back through the history of the Git book. This is indeed a bug: they changed the commit message without correspondingly changing the hashes. This particular commit message used to be "first commit\n" (note capitalisation); this was true at least as of https://github.com/progit/progit2/blob/fbb758a2369bcb02bbd8683a6a76e24e41b8e63c/book/10-git-internals/sections/objects.asc . The problem was introduced by 4f55250d90710652c0948853bb3ffcbd751adeee, and I'll fix it now.